# Calculation of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sin(x)^{ki}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

Is this formula correct?
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sin(x)^{ki}=\frac{i}{\sin(\ln(\sin(x)))-i\cos(\ln(\sin(x)))+i}$$ How is it possible to give a proof of this equality?
Thanks.

Comment: Which branch of $\ln$ are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sum is a geometric series with closed form, for $|\sin^i{x}| \lt 1$:

$$\frac{1}{1-(\sin{x})^i} = \frac{1}{1-e^{i \log{\sin{x}}}} = \frac{1}{1-\cos{\log{\sin{x}}} - i \sin{\log{\sin{x}}}}$$

Multiply numerator and denominator by $i$ and you have the sought-after expression.

Note that this is a purely formal expression, and that consideration of a branch of the log must be understood before attempting an actual calculation.

Comment: nice eye!...... +1

Comment: But the series is not convergent: $|(\sin x)^i|=1$.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre: that is not necessarily so.  And even if that were the case, we have a useful geometric series for the same reason we are allowed to consider the sum over $k$ of $e^{i k x}$.